# Vue3 POSTing JSON to .Net API

Tags: c#, json, .net, vue.js

I keep getting 400 bad request when I try to call my API POSTing data to it.
POST http://localhost:5081/Purchasing/TestCall/190200 400 (Bad Request)

Here is my Vue Call

```js
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    },
    body: JSON.stringify(lstOrders.value),
};
fetch("http://localhost:5081/Purchasing/TestCall/"+ workOrder.value, requestOptions)
```

The object in the array I created from these calls

```cs
//return Ok(lstPDFs.OrderBy(x => x.FileName));
return Ok(JsonSerializer.Serialize(lstPDFs.OrderBy(x => x.FileName)));
```

It looks like this JSON Data:
In dev tools here it is `console.log(myReturnedList)`

```
[[Target]]:Array(10)
0:{AutoID: 0, FileName: '4700.9359', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
1:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'I_101', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
2:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'I_102', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
3:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'I_103four', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
4:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'I_104', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
5:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'I_105GC', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
6:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'I_201', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
7:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'I_202MMEvolution', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
8:{AutoID: 0, FileName: 'MMEvo', FilePath: 'C:\\temp\\batchprint\\engserv\\190200\\Installation', FileSize: 0, CreatedDate: '0001-01-01T00:00:00', …}
```

So my Data is JSON which and a Object List which is what my next API call is expecting.
Here is my API Request Method

```cs
[EnableCors]
[HttpPost("TestCall/{projectNumber}")]
public IActionResult TestCall(string projectNumber, [FromBody] List<PDFFile> pdfs)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("TEST");

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Does the model `PDFFile` exactly match the the object type sent in your JSON array?

Comment: I would say yes? I am getting my JSON array from an API request that returns the PDFFile List, I'll double check that to see it is exact

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  Can you hit a breakpoint inside the endpoint?  Does the endpoint work with Postman?  Are there errors reported in any of the Output windows in Visual Studio during runtime?

Comment: I have swagger, my API request works with that. when I try to hit it with front end it fails. I tried changing json to plain text and i got a unsupported data format error when i sent it to API
the API never even hits the first breakpoint to retrieve the data

Comment: so going through my json array objects and yes its the same as the PDFFile object

Comment: YAYYY that did it! I found thank you!!!
It was object validation, in C# i wasnt accepting null values in my object I ended up using postman and it told me each property it was failing on Swagger did not